# Files go missing when copied over NFS: cp command does not throw errors

Tags: linux, bash, mount, nfs

I have a script that is copying files like this:

```
cp $MILL_OUTPUT/$JOB_ID"_"$DATE"_"*.afp $AFP_DIR/
test $? -ne 0 && exit 3
```

The engine that executes the bash script will stop processing if the script returns a non-zero value. However, yesterday some files were not copied, but the cp command did not return with a non-zero value.

The directory where the files are copied from (`$MILL_OUTPUT`) lies on a NFS share. Lately we've had some network stability issues where connections seem to drop for a few seconds. I am now wondering if the cp command did not abort because of the way the NFS share was mounted:

```
10.101.150.1:/mnt/wrk/                  /net/cmpmil             nfs4    _netdev,bg,intr,soft,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,nolock,proto=tcp,timeo=5,retrans=5,actimeo=10,retry=5 0 0
```

This mount configuration was created to prevent stale NFS mounts after a restart of the remote systems. I suspect that the `soft` parameter causes the missing files, though after searching I'm not sure that might be the problem.

Comment: `some files were not copied` – Can you tell if *the same* `cp` copied other files? Are you sure `$AFP_DIR` was properly set? My point is maybe `cp` really succeeded but the target directory was not what you think and you're looking in the wrong place. BTW, not quoting variables will get you into trouble sooner or later (although I'm not sure if it can be the culprit here).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, some files were copied - the issue happened on a production workflow. The workflow is used to preprocess customer invoices. Customer said there should be around 4000 invoices, once processing finished the printer only got 1500 invoices. Once I restarted the workflow 4000 invoices arrived on the printer - it definitively copied part of the files the first time, but not all of them. No changes were made to the workflow when restarting it. Or put otherwise: If we hadn't checked the number of invoices, nobody would've noticed that more than half of the invoices were missing.